# Generating daily statistics with MySQL

Tags: mysql, statistics

I need to generate daily sales statistics with my database called "orders" , one of its fields is called "date" (DATETIME).

My query is quite simple:

```
SELECT DAY(date) , COUNT(id_order)
FROM z_view_order_list
WHERE WEEK(date) = WEEK(NOW())
GROUP BY DAY(date)
LIMIT 7
```

The problem is that if for example there was no sales yesterday, yesterday will not be
shown on result, but I need it to be shown with 0 value.

Example of my actual result (Day/Sales):    27/3, 29/4, 30/2
Example of result that I need (Day/Sales):  27/3, 28/0, 29/4, 30/2, 31/0

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table `calendar`, with all days, and join your table on this calendar.

A way to create that calendar table :

http://www.richnetapps.com/using-mysql-generate-daily-sales-reports-filled-gaps/

then

```
SELECT Day(c.cal_date), COALESCE(COUNT(z.id_order), 0)
FROM calendar c
LEFT JOIN z_view_order_list z ON z.date = c.cal_date
WHERE WEEK(c.cal_date) = WEEK(NOW())
GROUP BY DAY(c.cal_date)
LIMIT 7
```

*ADVICE OF THE DAY*

Don't use Date as name for your field. Date is a type of a function, try to avoid confusion...

Comment: Thanks for response! I appreciate it very much but I don't want to add complexity to the database.  I have solved it by software, in my code (php) by creating and array of last month-days by this way:
for($x=0; $x<7;  $x++) $arrDays = date("d", time()-$x*86400);

Thanks for helping me and for your advice